# Apply automatic migration using cli in .net core 2.0 and entityframework core 2.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have defined the following application context class.

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLConnection")));
}
```

UserConfiguration.cs

```
internal class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Users");
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        }
    }
```

When I apply command Add-migration somemigration then it creates whole migration history with files and after `Update-Database` it creates database and table Accounts. However when I type `Update-Database -Verbose` then it only creates only database without table. What should I add to enable this?

Comment: Before running `Update-Database -Verbose`, did you run `Add-Migration migrationName` command? If not, run `Add-migration  migrationName` first. In addition, I suggest you keep `EF Core` version as `2.0.*` the same with project version. Did you install `EntityFrameworkcore` manually? I suggest you uninstall it. It has been included in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`.

Comment: I applied this, and still I need to use Add-migration to apply new tables. Update-Database -Verbose doesn't detect new changes.

Comment: Yes, you need to run `Add-Migration`, `Update-Database -Verbose`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) only shows verbose output, it did not implemente add-migration function. For the reason it could not be achieved by single command, I think it provides us to check whether the generated migrations is right.

Comment: @maciejka please refer http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx